# How to resume the identation in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone know of any shortcut that summarizes all indentations in vscode?

Example:

```
def function(x):
    print('Start')
    r = 1+x
    print('Complet')
    return r 

def function2(x):
    print('Start')
    r = 2+x
    print('Complet')
    return r
```

->

```
def function(x):

def function2(x):
```

this but using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: look in the Outline View

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're all top level, you can do `Fold All` (`editor.foldAll`) - by default bound to `Ctrl+K Ctrl+0`.